# Firebase user created by someone else

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my application, it should be possible to add new users by other users.

1. I'm having the problem that I can't just create an account - Firebase Authentication - with a random password for this new user, because it will automatically log in with this new account, using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.
2. If I just create a new doc in the usercollection (with the name, birthday, ... linked to an account's id), and afterwards this user creates an account (Firebase Authentication), I will need to check every collection's docs where this usercollection's docid is used and replace it with the created uid from `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. Also not a bulletproof solution...

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the [Firebase Admin Auth SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to [create a new user server-side](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user). This means you will have to implement some server-side solution if you don't already have one. An HTTP-triggered [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) would be a good option. If you're new to Cloud Functions, the [samples on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) are a good place to start. A very basic version of your function could look like this:

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const email = decodeURI(req.query.email);

  await admin.auth().createUser({
    email: email,
    password: "password", // however you're planning on creating the password goes here
  })
});
```

Your code will be more complex, but it's a starting point.